# AwakeFromNib auto layout stretch UIlabel to spacing on both side programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to add a UIlabel to a UIView class. 
it should be in the following format -15-Label(stretch to max width)-15.

Top spacing=15 and height fixed to 30.

Two issues with the following code:-
1) Label does not stretch to max width
2) Right side spacing does not show up , if the text it too long.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    view1 =[[UILabel alloc] init];

    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

    [self addSubview:view1];
    view1.text= @"Hello";

    NSDictionary *constraintViews=
    @{@"view1":view1};
    NSDictionary *metrics=@{@"spacing":@(15)};
    NSArray *hConstraints=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spacing-[view1]-spacing-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:allViews];


    NSArray *vConstraints=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-spacing-[view1(30)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:constraintViews];
    [self addConstraints:hConstraints];
    [self addConstraints:vConstraints];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

- Update the horizontal constraints like so:

  ```
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spacing-[view1]-spacing@751-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:constraintViews];
  ```
- Try adding the line below:

  ```
  [view1 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
  ```

2) I always set the `numberOfLines` property of a label to 0 by default, so that the label will autoresize vertically if the text needs to be shown in two or more lines. That being said, you would need to remove the fixed height constraint and the label will be the size of the it's contents like so:

```
view1.numberOfLines = 0;
NSArray *vConstraints=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-spacing-[view1]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:constraintViews];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: horizontal constraint still does not work it shows spacing of 15  on leading side but on trailing side it does not.

Comment: Try increasing the priority of that constraint to be 1000 (required).
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-spacing-[view1]-spacing@751-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:constraintViews];

Comment: It still did not work. I don't why the left side shows correct spacing, right side there is no spacing

Comment: I see its considering the intrinsic content size , so the its like 15-Label of width around 500-15. 500 is the intrinsic content size. thats where its messing up.

Answer (score 0):

I used this generic method for applying constraints of childView wrt to ParentView.Just pass your views to this method.

```
+ (void)applyConstraints:(UIView *)pChildView withSuperView:(UIView *)pParentView {
pChildView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
// Width.
CGFloat widthValue = pParentView.frame.size.width;
[pParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pChildView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:pParentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0  constant:widthValue]];
// Height.
CGFloat heightValue = pParentView.frame.size.height;
[pParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pChildView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:pParentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:heightValue]];
// X margin.
[pParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pChildView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterXWithinMargins
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:pParentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterXWithinMargins multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
// Y margin.
[pParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pChildView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterYWithinMargins
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:pParentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterYWithinMargins multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
}
```